# Installing JDK on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: java, elastic-beanstalk

I'm not entirely sure whether this belongs here or on StackOverflow, because it involves server admin, but it also involves a compiler.

It seems that the application on our Elastic Beanstalk cluster requires not just a JVM, but also a JDK, because it has the capability of installing extensions that it has to compile from Java source.

And we just now discovered, when we tried to use that capability on the cluster, instead of on a non-clustered development box, that the compiler isn't there.

Clearly, we need to customize what AWS uses to spin up new instances, so that it includes a working JDK.

But how?

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, one of our overseas developers found the answer for me.

1. Install the JDK on a cluster instance.
2. Change the Tomcat JDK home to point to it.
3. Create a custom AMI from the modified cluster node.
4. Note down the cluster's current AMI ID, in case something goes wrong.
5. Plug the custom AMI into the cluster, in its place.